# Trouble with DataTables Filtering when Using JavaScript Object for Conditional Behavior

Tags: r, shiny, dt

`I am working on an R Shiny application where I have implemented a DataTable using the DataTables library. I have added custom conditional behavior to certain columns using JavaScript (JS) code. The JS code aims to truncate cell content and provide a "Read more" option for cells with content exceeding a certain length.

The conditional behavior works as expected initially. However, I am encountering trouble with the DataTable's filtering functionality when the JS code is applied. The filters seem to get stuck in a "processing" state and do not update the displayed data accordingly.

I suspect that the issue arises due to a conflict between the JS code and the filtering mechanism of DataTables. It seems that the JS code interferes with the filtering process or causes processing delays.`

```
js<-"function(cell, cellData, rowData, rowIndex, colIndex) {
        if (cellData.length > 50) {
          var $cell = $(cell);
          $cell.contents().wrapAll('<div class=\\\"content\\\"></div>');
          var $content = $cell.find('.content');
          $cell.append($('<button>Read more</button>'));
          $btn = $cell.find('button');
          $content.css({
            height: '50px',
            overflow: 'hidden'
          });
          $cell.data('isLess', true);
          $btn.click(function () {
            var isLess = $cell.data('isLess');
            $content.css('height', isLess ? 'auto' : '50px');
            $(this).text(isLess ? 'Read less' : 'Read more');
            $cell.data('isLess', !isLess);
          });
        }

      }"
# Filtering and conditional behavior
output$table <- renderDT({
  # Filtering logic here (based on Owning Group and search terms)
  
  # DataTable initialization
  datatable(
    filtered_df,
    width = "100%",
    options = list(
      pageLength = 10,
      columnDefs = list(
        list(
          targets = 4:7,  # Specify columns 4, 5, 6, and 7
          createdCell = JS(js)  # JS code for conditional behavior
        )
      )
    ),
    rownames = FALSE,
    filter = list(
      position = "top",
      clear = FALSE,
      plain = FALSE
    )
  )
})
```

`In the above code, the JS code is responsible for applying the conditional behavior to columns 4, 5, 6, and 7. While the conditional behavior works initially, it causes the DataTable's filtering functionality to become unresponsive.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Is there a way to apply the JS code while preserving the functionality of the DataTable's filters? Alternatively, are there alternative approaches to achieve similar conditional behavior without relying heavily on JS code?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!
Here is a simplified code snippet showcasing the problematic code:

I attempted to apply a JavaScript (JS) code snippet to a DataTable in my R Shiny application. The JS code was intended to provide conditional behavior for specific columns by truncating cell content and adding a "Read more" option when the content exceeded a certain length.

Here's what I tried:

I added the JS code to the DataTable using the createdCell or render option within columnDefs.
I expected the DataTable to display the conditional behavior as intended, truncating long cell content and adding the "Read more" option.
However, when applying the JS code, the DataTable's filtering functionality became unresponsive. The filters kept showing a "processing" state and did not update the displayed data.
It seems that the application of the JS code caused conflicts or processing delays with the DataTable's filtering mechanism. As a result, the filtering functionality did not work as expected.

I would appreciate any guidance on how to resolve this issue or alternative approaches to achieve similar conditional behavior without impacting the DataTable's filtering functionality.`